# How to select a textview having an id from a custom listview in android?

Tags: java, android

I have a custom listview having the following layout:
[image: GUI view of the layout]

I have defined an onClick method for 'qadd' button and 'qsub' button in xml using `android:onClick` property.

In my Activity class how do I select the 'quantity' textView for current position?

I tried this but it only updates 'quantity' textView at first position.

```
public void addClicked(View v) {
        final int position = list.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent().getParent());
        long rec_id = adapter.getItemId(position);

        JSONObject o = (JSONObject) fullList.get(rec_id + "");

        TextView q = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity);

        int quantity = Integer.parseInt((String) q.getText());

        quantity++;

        q.setText(quantity + "");

        try {

            String price = o.getString("price");
            subtotal = subtotal + (Integer.parseInt(price) * quantity);
            total_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subtotal);
            total_text.setText(subtotal + "");

            // Log.d("position", price);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The above code goes wrong at this line:

```
TextView q = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantity);
```

It always selects the textView at first position.
Please ask if any other piece of code is needed.

Entire custom_list_layout.xml is as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
            android:padding="3dip" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/item_img"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item name"
                android:textColor="#040404"
                android:textSize="15dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_desc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Item description"
                android:textColor="#343434"
                android:textSize="10dip" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.75"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rupee"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="Rs. "
                    android:textColor="#EC1669"
                    android:textSize="10dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/item_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="0 "
                    android:textColor="#EC1669"
                    android:textSize="10dip"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="bottom|right" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/qadd"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="24dp"
                    android:minWidth="24dp"
                    android:onClick="addClicked"
                    android:text="+" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/quantity"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/qsub"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="24dp"
                    android:minWidth="24dp"
                    android:onClick="subClicked"
                    android:text="-" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[Link to my entire project.](http://www.mediafire.com/download/h3qnoocr3p8mn7i/myMenu.zip)

Comment: TextView t = ((TextView) v).findViewById(R.id.quantity);

Comment: It throws an error. Do you mean: 
TextView q = (TextView) ((TextView)v).findViewById(R.id.quantity); . However, it doesn't work. It throws NullPointerException,

Comment: Sry i meant TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

Comment: Nopes. NullPointerException for that too.

Comment: can you please post your layout xml too?

Comment: Well you have to define your quantity textview outside the addClicked because inside it cant access the original layout and the corresponding view refers to just the + button. So initialize your quantity textview in your onCreate method and update it inside your addCicked methd

Comment: If I define TextView in onCreate it throws NullPointerException in addClicked.

Comment: Really now? Please post your whole activity code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35850/discussion-between-abhijit-and-pavlos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your textview to address should be the one within the list item row you specify in XML for the list adapter.

If you're using a custom adapter, within getView you should wire up the textview as follows:

```
// create a new TextView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        View listView = convertView;

        if (listView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            // get layout from xml
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.browse_product_item, null);
        }


        final ListProductHolder holder;

        if (listView.getTag() != null) {
            holder = (listProductHolder) listView.getTag();
        } else {
            holder = new listProductHolder();
            listView.setTag(holder);

            holder.text= (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
```

One you have the proper TextView from within each item in the listView, then it's a simple process to wire up an OnClickListener for that view and respond to those click events.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that I can do it using OnClickListener in Adapter class. But isn't there a way to access the TextView if I use android:OnClick xml property?

Comment: I guess there is no other way and I have to go with the above method